# Why is my stylesheet not linking to my XHTML?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head> 
<title>Prac 3</title>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/> 

</head>

<body> 
<ul>
<li><a href="#Trade digital books in the midst of a pandemic.">Trade digital books in the midst of a pandemic.</a>.         </li>
<li><a href="#Worldwide ">Worldwide</a></li>
<li><a href="#South_Africa">South Africa</a></li>
<li><a href="#Conclusion">Conclusion</a></li>
<li><a href="#Sources">Sources</a></li>
</ul>
</body> 
</html>
```

My style sheet is not linking to my XHTML
but if it is a HTML it is working.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, but those doctypes are way out of date now (by over a decade). If your styles aren't applying, it sounds like the path to the stylesheet isn't right. You need to clarify where it is in relation to the HTML page.

Comment: include an example of the HTML that is working

Comment: Check your browser inspector for errors.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your example but had no issue. This is what I used 20 years ago for XHTML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
```

However, as was already commented, the community has moved on from XHTML. I believe this is the accepted standard these days:

[Anatomy of an HTML document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/Getting_started#anatomy_of_an_html_document)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Bottom line to answer your question: You indicate trouble with XHTML, but you probably shouldn't be using XHTML. So don't use it and there's no issue linking your CSS.

Comment: Thank you, I am a university student so we are only allowed to use that. Thanks for the help

Comment: We are only allowed to do XHTML for this assignment.